# Looking to store customer data in custom table

Tags: zend-framework, magento

I have created a new custom module and DB table for magento. What is the best wat to populate this with customer data.

For example when a new customer is created I want to store the ID of this customer in this new table as well and then use this ID to display various information in a new section within the admin.

I have created the new section but just not sure how to do the first part. The reason I want to do this is that I want to assign each customer a specific discount per category.

Thanks
Robert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Robert,
there is a better way for doing this, and you do not need to create a module.

You can associate your customers to groups in the Customer->Customer Groups  menu.

After create the customer groups, you can create a specific discount for this group and for each category. For doing this, you should:

1. Go to Promotions -> Shopping cart price rules
2. Click in Add new
3. Set the name and select the group to apply
4. Click on the Conditions tab
5. Add a Product Attribute combination rule, and add Product Attribute Category as the attribute to verify.
6. Select the category (or categories) that this rule applies.

Example:
[image]

---

But if you want to proceed with the original idea, I suggest you [create a customer attribute](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/adding-magento-attribute-with-custom-input-renderer/), instead of creating a new table. By doing this, the custom attribute can be shown at the customer information with no need to create another admin page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the problem is there is quite a complex flashing calculation required to work out the price and the discount needs to be applied at a certain point. For example: Choose Material, Girth or Material, APPLY DISCOUNT, No of Bends, multiple by length... This is why I thought a custom section to handle this would be better as I need to be be able to work this discount into the calculation. Also this discount is different for each category for one customer! So each customer might have 10 different discounts. What do you think?

Comment: I still guess that you can do it inside magento. You can create customer groups, and add this groups into the discount/promotional rules. 
Its more difficult to apply, but you can do it as shown above, and creating combinations of the customer attributes/group and with the product attributes.

Comment: Ok, I think I have enough now to figure the best way to do this now. THanks